# 5 value unicode character in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode

The aim is to show . The [unicode value](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D445) `\u1D445` is interpreted as `\u1D44` + 2 and printed as ᵄ2 in ggplot2. Any solutions?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")
set.seed(42) 
df <- data.frame(date = 1:10 , value = cumsum(runif(10 , max = 10)) )
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value)) 
p <- p + geom_line()
p + geom_label(aes(label = "Kruskal-Wallis Anova Dim2 by:\nCategory: p < .001\nRegion: p < .001\nCategory*Region: p < .001\n\u1D445\u00B2 = 0.49",  x=2, y=40, family="Times New Roman")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the character using the wrong syntax.  `\u` only takes 4 hex digits, as you saw, but there's also `\U` which takes up to 8.  This is the same syntax as C99.

I can't run your Windows-specific code to test, but that should at least help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
p + geom_label(aes(label = "R",  x=2, y=40, fontface="italic", family="Times New Roman"))
```

This is an inherent feature included in `geom_label`, so does not need any other library.

Comment: Failed to mention that it is not 1 character. A whole string with just 1 character in italic, which is very hard to manipulate in R. `paste()`, `expression()` and other solutions don't work. Actual code is much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

My dirty solution is not to use `\u`.

```
p + geom_label(aes(label = "Kruskal-Wallis Anova Dim2 by:\nCategory:  < .001\nRegion:  < .001\nCategory*Region:  < .001\n\u00B2 = 0.49",  x=2, y=40, family="Times New Roman")
```

it creates problems in displaying the string in R studio. And I am not sure if the letters are really in the same font, and italic versions of normal R and p.